# Requesting the device token

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification

When dealing with push notifications didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken does the job of registering the device for notifications and receiving the deviceToken that we can use after that, but what happens if there is no internet at the time the app launches and didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken runs?

Is there a way to force didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken to run again and receive the token?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read this Technical Note: [TN2265 - Troubleshooting Push Notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html)

It says:

> When the first push-capable app is installed, iOS or Mac OS X attempts
>   to establish a persistent network connection to the push service that
>   will be shared by all push-capable apps on the system. If neither
>   delegate callback
>   application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken: nor
>   application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError: is
>   called, that means that this connection has not yet been established.
>
> This is not necessarily an error condition. The system may not have
>   Internet connectivity at all because it is out of range of any cell
>   towers or Wi-Fi access points, or it may be in airplane mode. **Instead
>   of treating this as an error, your app should continue normally,
>   disabling only that functionality that relies on push notifications.**
>
> Keep in mind that network availability can change frequently. Once the
>   persistent connection to the push service succeeds, one of the
>   previously-mentioned application delegate methods will be called.

You should call `registerForRemoteNotificationTypes` every time the application launches, even if there is no network connectivity. The push framework handles the rest. In didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken you send the token to your server (if not sent already or the token has changed).

Also check the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG):

> By requesting the device token and passing it to the provider every
>   time your application launches, you help to ensure that the provider
>   has the current token for the device. If a user restores a backup to a
>   device or computer other than the one that the backup was created for
>   (for example, the user migrates data to a new device or computer), he
>   or she must launch the application at least once for it to receive
>   notifications again. If the user restores backup data to a new device
>   or computer, or reinstalls the operating system, the device token
>   changes. Moreover, never cache a device token and give that to your
>   provider; always get the token from the system whenever you need it.
>   If your application has previously registered, calling
>   registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: results in the operating system
>   passing the device token to the delegate immediately without incurring
>   additional overhead.

Comment: ok, but there's a delta time between each try iOS makes, right? what if I need it now? Any way to make it check it right now?

Comment: +1 - This showed me that my company firewall was blocking Apple sandbox server due the high port number. Thank you.